# Accumulating associative array values PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I have this code:

And this is my data structure:

[image]

**totalMes Function:**

```
    function totalMes(){
  //Genera un array con el total de cada mes
  global $tickets;
  $totales = ["juego" => '', "precioTicket" => 0, "cantidadTickets" => 0];
  for ($i=0; $i < 12; $i++) {
      foreach($tickets[$i] as $juegos){
          foreach ($juegos as $key => $value){
              $totales[$key] += $value;
              $totalMes[$i] = $totales['precioTicket'] * $totales['cantidadTickets'];
          }
          $totales = ["juego" => '', "precioTicket" => 0, "cantidadTickets" => 0];
      }
    }
    return $totalMes;
}
```

Now when I enter a new value to array tickets and then I call `totalMes` function. It accumulates me only the last value of the array tickets.

**Example:**

```
function ingresarJuego($mes, $juego, $precioTicket, $cantidadTickets){
  global $tickets;
  $juego = ["juego" => $juego, "precioTicket" => $precioTicket, "cantidadTickets" => $cantidadTickets];
  array_push($tickets[$mes], $juego);
  return $tickets;
}
```

This is my array `totalMes`, before entering a new record to array tickets:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 100
    [1] => 1886
    [2] => 774
    [3] => 720
    [4] => 7719
    [5] => 5238
    [6] => 2430
    [7] => 2736
    [8] => 1080
    [9] => 315
    [10] => 621
    [11] => 6536
)
```

Now if I enter a value in array tickets and then calculate `totalMes` again. it does not accumulate the values ​​if the treads with the last record.

```
Array
(
    [0] => 4  // When it should be 100 + 4
    [1] => 1886
    [2] => 774
    [3] => 720
    [4] => 7719
    [5] => 5238
    [6] => 2430
    [7] => 2736
    [8] => 1080
    [9] => 315
    [10] => 621
    [11] => 6536
)
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand well your questio but

Could be you need  and add  for the value

```
 array_push($tickets[$mes],$tickets[$mes] + $juego);
```